# How to remove slashes "/" before inserting into database in - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I show my products by title, and sometimes one of my products will have a "/" in its title. Every time I go click on a product details, it gives me an error, because there is a slash in the URL. So I need to remove the slash, or show an error message before inserting into database in the back-end.

This is how I insert my product: (I'm using *stripslashes*, but its not doing anything)

```html
public function addPostProduct(ProductRequest $request) {


        // Create the product in DB
        $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => stripslashes($request->input('product_name')),
        ]); 


        // Save the product into the Database.
        $product->save();

        // Flash a success message
        flash()->success('Success', 'Product created successfully!');

        // Redirect back to Show all products page.
        return redirect()->route('admin.product.show');
    }
```

This is my Request check:

```html
class ProductRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'product_name' => 'required|max:75|min:3|unique:products',
        ];
    }

}
```

And this is my route to display an individual product by title. ( I tried {!! !!}, but it doesn't work either)

```html
 <a href="{!!  route('show.product', $product->product_name) !!}">Products Show</a>
```

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of  `stripslashes()`. You could also use `urlencode()` but the problem then becomes if you're making a comparison against the name it won't be correct to parse in the route. There is also a way to resolve that, too.

Comment: " it gives me an error, because there is a slash in the URL"  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: it still inserts into the database with a "/"

Comment: it is a input field, if that makes a diffrence or not?

Comment: It can be in the database with a slash, you just need to urlencode() it if it's in a url....

Comment: where would I place the urlencode() at? In the same place as I inserted stripslashes?

Comment: in your href instead of `$product->product_name` use  `urlencode($product->product_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_replace

```
$title = "product/124"; 

echo stripslashes($title) . "<br />"; 

echo str_replace("/", "", $title). "<br />";
```

Or to clarify it further:

```
      $product_name =  str_replace("/", "",$request->input('product_name'));
 // Create the product in DB
        $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $product_name
        ]);
```